# Hierarchical filtered lookup in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, filter, associative

I have been pondering a data structure problem for a while, but can't seem to come up with a good solution. I can not shake off the feeling that the solution is simple and I'm just not seeing it, however, so hopefully you guys can help!

Here is the problem: I have a large collection of objects in memory. Each of them has a number of data fields. Some of the data fields, such as an ID, are unique for each objects, but others, such as a name, can appear in multiple objects.

```
class Object {
    size_t id;
    std::string name;
    Histogram histogram;
    Type type;
    ...
};
```

I need to organize these objects in a way that will allow me to quickly (even if the number of objects is relatively large, i.e. millions) filter the collection given a specification of an arbitrary number of object members while all members that are left unspecified count as wildcards. For example, if I specify a given `name`, I want to retrieve all the objects whose name member equals the given name. However, if I then add a histogram to the query, I would like the query to return only the objects that match in both the `name` and the `histogram` fields, and so on. So, for example, I'd like a function

```
std::set<Object*> retrieve(size_t, std::string, Histogram, Type)
```

that can both do

```
retrieve(42, WILDCARD, WILDCARD, WILDCARD)
```

as well as

```
retrieve(42, WILDCARD, WILDCARD, Type_foo)
```

where the second call would return fewer or equally as many objects as the first one. Which data structure allows queries like this and can both be constructed and queried in reasonable time for object counts in the millions?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First you could use [Boost Multi-index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) to implement efficent lookup over differnt members of your `Object`.  This could help to limit the number of elements to consider. As a second step you can simply use a lambda expression to implement a predicate for `std::find_if` to get first element or use `std::copy_if` to copy all elements to an target sequence. If you decide to use boost you can use Boost Range with [filtering](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/filtered.html).